# What is normal SCSI error handling process (scsi_eh_3) CPU time usage?

Tags: central-processing-unit, time, scsi, top

Last week I got setup with a new dedicated server that is running 4x SCSI drives in RAID 10 on CentOS. The machine is pretty lightly loaded at the moment and has been running for 8 days.

The process 'scsi_eh_3' has a CPU time of 13:09.67 in top. This is 3x the next closest CPU time of 4:03.93 for mysqld. Is it normal for the scsi error handling process to use this much CPU time? (Seems like it goes to 0.3% usage ever 5 seconds.) Could this be an indicator that one or more of the drives is having issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a 100% answer but my scsi_eh_x processes on a couple of servers that have been up for a long long time show 0 cpu time, so I would say yes, get the diags for you scsi card and run them looks like you have something going wrong.